# first column name is circled by double quote after reading from csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

i use the following codes to read data from csv using read_csv, but after i print the result and found the first column name is circled by double quote, but other column names are normal,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

path1 = "C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\ml-    1m\\SELECT_FROM_HRAP2P3_SAAS_ZTXDMPARAM_201611291745.csv"
frame1 = pd.read_csv(path1,encoding='utf8',dtype = {'COMPANY_ORGANIZATION': str})

frame1
```

[The output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhNGZ.jpg)

Comment: So what's the question here? how to remove the quotes as a post-processing step or why this happened? You'll need to post the raw text from the first few lines of your csv in order for us to answer that

Comment: "PROJECT","AREA","ISO_COUNTRY_CODE","COUNTRY_CODE","COMPANY_ORGANIZATION","CUTOVER","PERSNO_LOW","PERSNO_HIGH","PERSNO_USED","ST_FISCAL_YR","ST_DM_PERIOD","SCRAMBLE_DATA","TARGET_TENANT","TIMESTAMP","USER"
AP-AU3         ,HR,AUS,"616","0155",2016-08-05,0,0,-1,2016-01-01,2015-01-01,N,"1         ",2016-08-17-09.31.34.727984,ANICK

Comment: sorry, don't know how to format this text from my csv file, and what i want to know why this happen, thanks,

Comment: I see exactly the same issue. Only the first column is in double quotes. Don't know why

Comment: This answer helped me resolve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256049/1526703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) column names by value `"`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('"')
```

Or if all values contains `"` use parameter `quotechar='"'` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

Comment: what about `quotechar` ?

Comment: i had tried to add quotechar='“', but do not work, the first column name still shows like this: "PROJECT",

Comment: if i use them all, the interesting thing is: now it shows as "PROJECT

Comment: what is your pandas version?

Comment: i try to use this: frame1.columns = frame1.columns.str.replace('"',''), it works,

Comment: i am curious about the reason for this double quotes only for the first column name,

Comment: my pandas version is 0.17.0

Comment: So you can overwrite value by `df.columns = ['PROJECT'] + df.columns[1:].tolist()`

Comment: i upgrade my pandas to 0.19, and then this strange problem disappear,