# csv module returning a BOM for first column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, unicode

I have a csv file formatted like this:

```
type,type_mapping, style,style_mapping,Count
Residential,Residential,Antique,Antique,109
Antique,Residential,Antique,Antique,48
Apt/Garage,Commercial,Apt/Garage,Apartment,1
```

I am parsing it using the csv module in Python (version 3).  Here is my code:

```
import os
import csv

typeXref = dict()
with open('xref.csv') as csvData:
    csvRead = csv.reader(csvData)
    headers = next(csvRead)

    for index, row in enumerate(csvRead):
        typeXref[index] = {key: value for key, value in zip(headers, row)} 

print(typeXref)
```

For some reason my first column continually returns the byte order mark `\ufeff`for the first column in the header.

```
408: {'\ufefftype': 'Residential', 'type_mapping': 'Residential', 
      ' style': 'Antique', 'style_mapping': 'Antique', 'Count': '109'}}
```

I assume this is due to the way I'm opening the file, reading the content with the `csv` module, or generating the file.

I can figure out how to decode that one field, but would rather ensure I'm generating the file correctly, or using the `csv` module property.

Comment: did you already try with `with open('xref.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvData:` ?

Comment: Excellent idea.  I just tried that and I still retrieve the same BOM.  I suspect it is something along these lines however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to tell that you are reading an utf-8 file with BOM:

```
with open('xref.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvData:
    ....
```

Then the BOM will be stripped

Comment: Thanks! Finally found this after some searching. Answers suggesting to use `quotechar` or `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` didn't work for me.